# Возможно ли отследить в чате сообщение c inline режимом?

Tags: json, telegram-bot, telegram

JSON сообщение в боте,

```
{
  "ok":true,
  "result":[
    {
      "update_id":465368093,
      "message":{
        "message_id":94,
        "from":{
          "id":375937375,
          "is_bot":false,
          "first_name":"butthead",
          "username":"bu77h4ad",
          "language_code":"ru-RU"
        },
        "chat":"",
        "id":-1001165301427,
        "title":"Qqqq",
        "type":"supergroup"
      },
      "date":1518276557,
      "text":"!!!EFDSADFKASD:"
    }
  ]
}
```

так отображается 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как определить боту что сообщение написали в чате с кнопками (inline сообщение) ?